# Why are my stroke lines shiny/still showing up in my Leaflet map?

Tags: css, leaflet, geojson

Here's a rawgit of my map: https://cdn.rawgit.com/elbertwang3/asiansintheus/bf7ea219/index.html

In the first map, I've set my opacity and weight of the stroke line to 0, but the stroke lines are still showing up! They're not completely there, but on some intersections they are shiny/half there. Can I get rid of them or can I make them uniform somehow? It's making the choropleth look really strange. For reference, I've used a geojson to render the county boundaries, so I'm not sure if this is a Leaflet issue or a geojson issue.

Here is the part where I'm styling my map:

```
var getColor = chroma.scale(['#451A53','#40968B','#FDE733']).domain([0,110000])

function style(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties['2009']),
        color: 'white',
        weight: 0,
        opacity: 0,
        fillOpacity: 1

    };
}
L.geoJson(countyData, {style: style}).addTo(countymap);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RTFM. Let me quote from the [Leaflet API documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#path-stroke), the section about polygon/polyline options inherited from `L.Path`:

> `stroke`  `Boolean`   `true`  Whether to draw stroke along the path. Set it to `false` to disable borders on polygons or circles.

Thus, you should set a `stroke` option with a value of `false`. That will tell the vector renderer (SVG or Canvas) to explicitly skip the stroke.

---

Your case, however, might be one of [slivers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliver_polygon) due to [polygon simplification](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify/). That directly depends on the [`smoothfactor` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#polyline-smoothfactor) of polylines and polygons. Please be aware there are performance implications.